# How to sort opencv KeyPoints according to the response?

Tags: c++, opencv

I've some OpenCV KeyPoints, and they are stored as `vector<KeyPoint>` or `list<KeyPoint>`.
How to sort them according to the response of the KeyPoints to obtain the best n keypoints?

Regards.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking at the documentation, and guessing you are trying to do [something like this](http://opencv.itseez.com/doc/user_guide/ug_features2d.html),

Here is [how KeyPoint is implemented](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/features2d_common_interfaces_of_feature_detectors.html) in OpenCV.

So from what I understand, what you want to use is the response element:

```
float response; // the response by which the most strong keypoints have been selected. Can be used for the further sorting or subsampling
```

So this is definitely what I would be going to in your case. 
Create a function that sorts your vector by response :)

Hope this helps

**EDIT**:

Trying to take advantage of Adrian's advice (This is my first cpp code though, so expect to have some corrections to perform)

```
// list::sort
#include <list>
#include <cctype>
using namespace std;

// response comparison, for list sorting
bool compare_response(KeyPoints first, KeyPoints second)
{
  if (first.response < second.response) return true;
  else return false;
}

int main ()
{
  list<KeyPoints> mylist;
  list<KeyPoints>::iterator it;

  // opencv code that fills up my list

  mylist.sort(compare_response);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: If I store them as `list<KeyPoint>`, I am wondering if there is anyway to sort it like a simple `list.sort()`?

Comment: Yes u can, look at the list documentation: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/list/sort/ . You can just use a custom function for the "comp" that gets 2 KeyPoint parameters and compares them by the response. Than you just give that method to the list sort.

Comment: The thing that gets me is that I don't know whether a 'response' with a number closer to positive infinity is better than a 'response' closer to negative infinity or the other way around. 

I'm going to assume that a more positive response is better.

Comment: you can simplify `compare_response` and just do `return first.response < second.response`

Answer (score 6):

I've stored the keypoints as `std::vector<cv::KeyPoint>` and sorted them with:

```
 std::sort(keypoints.begin(), keypoints.end(), [](cv::KeyPoint a, cv::KeyPoint b) { return a.response > b.response; });
```

Note: Usage of C++ 11 required for lambda-expression.

Answer (score 3):

if you store keypoints in a vector:

```
#include <algorithm> // std::sort
#include <vector> // std::vector

int main() {
    std::vector<KeyPoint> keypoints;

    // extract keypoints right here

    std::sort(keypoints.begin(), keypoints.end(), response_comparator);

    // do what ever you want with keypoints which sorted by response
}

bool response_comparator(const KeyPoint& p1, const KeyPoint& p2) {
    return p1.response > p2.response;
}
```